# JSP add item to list like in java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I would like to do the following thing in JSP:

```
List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
for( Arulista aru: Arulista){
list.add(aru.aruneve);
}
```

I did the following but it's not working:

```
<c:forEach items="${Arulista}" var="aru">
$list=${aru.aruneve}   // $List.add(aru.aruneve) But either not working 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsp's are for display not building lists.  You should transform the list in your controller and then display it in the jsp.